# Spring Boot Callback after client receives resource?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm creating an endpoint using Spring Boot which executes a combination of system commands (java.lang.Runtime API) to generate a zip file to return to the client upon request, here's the code.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "generateZipFile")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> generateZipFile(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) throws IOException {
        org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource = null;
        //generate zip file using commandline 

        resource = service.generateTmpResource(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"randomFile.zip\"")
                    .body(resource);
        //somehow delete generated file here after client receives it 
    }
```

I cannot keep stacking up the files on the server for obvious disk limit reasons, so I'm looking for a way to delete the files as soon as the client downloads them. Is there a solution in Spring Boot for this? I basically need to hook a callback that would do the cleanup after the user receives the resource.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, `afterCompletion` was the callback I needed. The only challenge I had to deal with was passing through the id of the resource to cleanup, which I handled by adding a header in my controller method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "generateZipFile")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> genereateZipFile(@RequestParam("id") Integer id,
                                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
    org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource = myService.generateTmpResource(id);;
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip")
            .header(MyInterceptor.TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER, id.toString())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"someFile.zip\"")
            .body(resource);

}
```

The interceptor code:

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public static final String TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER = "Tmp-ID";

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                Object handler,
                                Exception ex) {
        if(response == null || !response.containsHeader(TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER)) return;
        String tmpFileId = response.getHeader(TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER);
        myService.cleanup(tmpFileId);
    }
}
```

For more information about interceptors see [here](https://o7planning.org/en/11689/spring-boot-interceptors-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new thread but a best solution would be create a ThreadPoolExecutor in order to manage threads or also Scheduled annotation helps us.

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        service.cleanup(id);
    }
}.start();
```

**UPDATED**

A best answer, it would be using a **Stack** combine with **Thread**.
Here is the solution that I've done.

https://github.com/jjohxx/example-thread

Comment: I've done that solution in order to run a new thread for "cleanup"  because when you keep on the same thread you will cleanup a file on the same thread that you should remove later. it's because you're receiving an empty file.

Comment: What guarantees that your thread will not delete the resource before the original thread finishes serving the file? I posted an answer with a working solution.

Comment: You can wait the current thread finishes and run this new thread so I give ideas like ThreadPoolExecutor can help you in order to manage threads.

Comment: Here is the example that I've been talking you https://github.com/jjohxx/example-thread . You can take a look at the moment when you get the response after that, what you are thinking of doing will be executed.  @ALTN

Comment: Hahaha xD it seems that you don't understand the logic on it I created a service that is a thread which will keep alive all time on controller. The thread will sleep by 2 seconds if it doesn't contain an element I did that because with this implementation you can support around 65'000 requests concurrently. You can test it and verify this result using gatling tool. One always tries to improve. Kind regards :).

Comment: @ALTN, this guy has gone way above and beyond to try and help you, and you are just being actively hostile to him in response. There's absolutely no way I'd have spent time demonstrating the answer that I'm suggesting after being told that I don't know what I'm talking about by the person I'm trying to help. How about attempting a tiny bit of courtesy, regardless of whether or not the solution is what you're looking for? You might find that you learn something.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376035/abuse-flag-declined-for-a-user-repeatedly-attacking-another-user)

Comment: Alright I admit it I'm a bit guilty here, my apologies to @JonathanJohx. I still didn't change my opinion though, the proposed solution doesn't work, there's nothing in the answerer solution that guarantees the chain of execution, the deletion of the resource before/while it is being served is still a problem.

Comment: It's no problem, thanks everyone for the feedback. @DaveyDaveDave I appreciate your comment. kind regards.!