# Rest service download file and delete it after that

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have the current code for download a file:

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileName:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
try {
    Path filePath = Paths.get(directoryPath).resolve(fileName);
    Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
    if (resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", fileName);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(resource);
    } else {
    logger.error("File not found: " + fileName );
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Error while downloading file: " + fileName, e);
}
return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

but now i need to implement logic to delete the file in some conditions. I tried to create the `Resource` object and delete it after that but the file is deleted before fully download it. How can I delete the file after file is downloaded or stopped by the client?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

The solution was to add an Interceptor and the `afterCompletion()`. In the `afterCompletion()` the needed logic for deleting the file was implemented.

Example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "generateZipFile")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> genereateZipFile(@RequestParam("id") Integer id,
                                                 RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
    org.springframework.core.io.Resource resource = myService.generateTmpResource(id);;
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip")
            .header(MyInterceptor.TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER, id.toString())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"someFile.zip\"")
            .body(resource);

}


The interceptor code:

@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public static final String TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER = "Tmp-ID";

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                Object handler,
                                Exception ex) {
        if(response == null || !response.containsHeader(TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER)) return;
        String tmpFileId = response.getHeader(TMP_RESOURCE_ID_HEADER);
        myService.cleanup(tmpFileId);
    }
}
```

Explanations taken from here: [Spring Boot Callback after client receives resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036981/spring-boot-callback-after-client-receives-resource)

**Old (does bot work properly):**

You can add a `finally` clause to your try catch in which you check if the file exists, and if yes, then delete the file.

The `finally` clause is executed guaranteed in ANY scenario and it is executed after `try` and `catch`.

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileName:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
} finally {
    ... delete the file here if it exists
}
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The file is deleted before fully downloading.

Comment: Then please check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036981/spring-boot-callback-after-client-receives-resource

Comment: Following the link you gave me I added Interceptor and afterCompletion method. In afterCompletion I added the logic for deleting the file and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I edited my answer so other developers can find the solution too!